# How to import first two values for each line in CSV file | PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, search, powershell-ise

I have a CSV file that generates everyday, and generates with data such as:

```
windows:NT:v:n:n:d:n:n:n:n:m:n:n
```

I should also mention that that example is one of 3,900+ lines, and not every line of data has the same number of "columns". What I'm trying to do is import just the first two "columns" of data into a variable. For this example, it would be "Windows" and "NT", nothing else.

How would I go about doing this? I've tried using -delimiter ':', and not much luck.

Comment: You're trying to import both columns for 3900+ rows in the same variable? What type of variable are you planning on using since that would make the question way more clear?

Comment: Maybe variable was a bad choice of words. I'm just trying to upload it so I can then use it in a "ForEach" on the next line. Honestly whatever it takes to make it work

Comment: you might even be able to include it in the foreach so that you'll read a line every loop depending on whether you need to do a foreach for each of the lines

Comment: You could try a for loop. In the loop split the line by ":" and then call only the first two indexes to start making a variable

Answer (score 2):

The number of lines shouldn't matter.

My approach from comment (to your previous question) should work,
if there is no header and you only want the first two columns,
just specify Header 1,2

```
> import-csv .\strange.csv -delim ':' -Header (1..2) |Where 2 -eq 'NT'

1       2
-       -
windows NT
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for building the entire array

```
$Splitted_List = @()

foreach($Line in Get-Content '.\myfilewithuseragents.txt'){           
    $Splitted = $Line -split ":"
    $Splitted_Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
        $part1 = $splitted[0]
        $part2 = $Splitted[1]        
    }
    $Splitted_List.Add($Splitted_Object) | Out-Null    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For every line you'll just read the line and with the string from that line, you're easily able to split it

```
$useragent = "windows:NT:v:n:n:d:n:n:n:n:m:n:n"
```

Then the first part will be referenced to as `$useragent.Split(":")[0]`, the second as `$useragent.Split(":")[1]`, etc.

---

Including the for-loop that would be something like

```
foreach($useragent in Get-Content '.\myfilewithuseragents.txt') {
  $splitted = $useragent.Split(":")
  $part1 = $splitted[0]
}
```

Comment: How should I go about doing this if I get an error that reads "... does not contain a method named 'Split'"?

Comment: I'm quite sure this should work as .Split() is a method on every string. Are you sure you wrote the code like this?

[The answer @LotPings gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714292/6367506) is the more official solution, although I wasn't sure how that would work with varying column lengths